# How to express that there are only 3 orange apples in predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to figure out how to limit the items I want to express to a certain number.

For example: For all apples out there, there are exactly 3 apples that are orange.

`A(x)` = x is an apple

`O(x)` = x is orange

I really have no idea how to start this, not even sure which quantifier to use. Would really appreciate some advice in how to break down these problems in an efficient way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By 'only 3' do you mean 'exactly 3' or 'at most 3'?

Comment: Hey, exactly 3.

Comment: OK, then try saying that there are three different apples that are orange .. but not a fourth orange apple different from those three. For 'different', use the $\neq$ ... which is short for $\neg =$

Comment: That's exactly where I'm not sure how to proceed.. :/

Comment: Ok... can you just say that there are three different apples?  What quantifier do you think you need?

Comment: the existential one I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98601/discussion-between-bram28-and-user472288).

Comment: The way I am reading the problem, it does not require there are other apples than those three. So it could be just those three.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Bram! I think I got this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, several ways to do this:

Probably the most straightforward way is to say that there are three distinct orange apples and no more:

$\exists x \exists y \exists z (A(x) \land O(x) \land A(y) \land O(y) \land A(z) \land O(z) \land  x \neq y \land x \neq z \land y \neq z\land \neg \exists w (A(w) \land O(w) \land  w \neq x \land w \neq y \land w \neq z))$

But another way of thinking about this is:  there are three distinct apples, and any object is an orange apple if and only if it is one of those:

$\exists x \exists y \exists z (x \neq y \land x \neq z \land y \neq z \land \forall w ((A(w) \land O(w)) \leftrightarrow  (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

This is more efficient ... but probably a little harder to grasp.